# Changing Style of TTrackBar makes it`s Tracking disable

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, firemonkey-style

I want to change the style of a TTrackBar component. I have added an Image control to TTrackBarHThumb style to show as the thumb button, but now the tracking not working, when I click and drag the thumb button it not move with the mouse cursor.

I know this is because the click of mouse hit on the Image instead of the thumb button, but there is not another way to change the thumb button. There is a style named `hthumb` but it has no any property to change the bitmap of thumb

How can I change the thumb button of TTrackBar without adding a new Image control ? or how to make the tracking works when using an image as thumb button ?

I`m using Delphi XE 6 and my project is a FireMonkey Desktop Application

Comment: It sounds like something needs its `HitTest` property toggled...

Comment: I changed HitTest of Image to False but not work. Is it possible to pass the mouse click from Image to thumb button ?!

Comment: Jerry is probably correct - HitTest may need to be turned off on some component that **contains** the TTrackBar - it may not be visually obvious. (Look at Delphi's "Structure" tool for clues)  If it's not too complex, maybe you could add the FMX file of the form to your question.